# Bootstrap 4 set a width of input-group inputs

Tags: html, css, position, bootstrap-4

Can you help me with this problem? I have an `input-group` within *bootstrap 4*. In my `input-group` I have 2 inputs, first with prepend and second with append.

It's wrapped in a `col-12` `div` in a `form-group` and I need to set the `width` of the first input and second to some specific (but different) value. I tried to set the `width` in my custom css, but without success. Is it possible? I know, that I can set it via wrapping it in a div with another col, but than I have both input below and not side by side.

Code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="telephone">Telephone</label>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-12">
            <div class="input-group telephone-input">
              <div class="input-group-prepend preselection-prepend">
                  <div class="input-group-text">+</div>
              </div>
              <input class="form-control" id="preselection" type="text" maxlength="3" name="preselection" placeholder="Preselection" autocomplete="off" required>
              <input class="form-control" id="telephone" placeholder="Telephone number" type="tel" maxlength="11" name="telephone" autocomplete="off" required>
              <span class="placeholder" id="tele-holder"></span>
              <div class="input-group-append" id="preselectionToggle">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                 <i class="far fa-plus-square"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
    
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-SlE991lGASHoBfWbelyBPLsUlwY1GwNDJo3jSJO04KZ33K2bwfV9YBauFfnzvynJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: What have you tried to set the widths? What exactly are "some values"? Wrapping them in columns should make them side-by-side. As explained in the [Bootstrap 4 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-grid) there are a few different ways to align form inputs. If you wan to align inputs **side-by-side** you *should* wrap them in columns.

Comment: Yes, but i want, as i described, to make first input, for example, 80px width and seccond 150px width, becouse for telephone preselection i need only width for max 3 numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution. I tried set max-width instead of only width and it works.
For the above example it would be:

```css
#preselection {
  max-width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="telephone">Telephone</label>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-12">
            <div class="input-group telephone-input">
              <div class="input-group-prepend preselection-prepend">
                  <div class="input-group-text">+</div>
              </div>
              <input class="form-control" id="preselection" type="text" maxlength="3" name="preselection" placeholder="Preselection" autocomplete="off" required>
              <input class="form-control" id="telephone" placeholder="Telephone number" type="tel" maxlength="11" name="telephone" autocomplete="off" required>
              <span class="placeholder" id="tele-holder"></span>
              <div class="input-group-append" id="preselectionToggle">
              <div class="input-group-text">
                 <i class="far fa-plus-square"></i>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
    
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-SlE991lGASHoBfWbelyBPLsUlwY1GwNDJo3jSJO04KZ33K2bwfV9YBauFfnzvynJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 13):

You can do it with class `w-50` and  `w-100`

like this

```
<div class="input-group">
   <div class="input-group-prepend w-50">
     <span class="input-group-text w-100">label</span>
   </div>
   <input type="text" class="form-control " />
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

I've found a solution on the internet and you can visit it at  [codeply](https://www.codeply.com/go/wv5NMmTgwq/bootstrap-4-input_group-prepend-equal-width)!.

It is pretty neat and simple. To do so, you just need to add the following `CSS` to your stylesheet.

```
.input-group>.input-group-prepend {
    flex: 0 0 30%;
}
.input-group .input-group-text {
    width: 100%;
}
```

To set the width of the `input-group-text`, just change the value of the `flex` of the `input-group`, for instance, as seen above `30%` of the total width.

Thank the author of the link above for this simple code snippet.